# python scroll a specific scrollbar vertically

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using python selenium to scroll a webpage, i am trying to get to the bottom of the page by clicking on the scroll element but it's returning this error: `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds`

My code so far:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
scrollbar_needed = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='antiscroll-scrollbar antiscroll-scrollbar-vertical antiscroll-scrollbar-shown']")
actions.click_and_hold(scrollbar_needed).move_by_offset(0,5000).release().perform()
```

Is there another way to scroll using the path of "scrollbar_needed"?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways of scrolling through a dynamic webpage.

**option 1:** If you want to scroll a specific limit you can use this

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")
```

**option 2:** If you want to scroll and reach to end of the page you can use this

```
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

**option 3:** If it is lazy loading page you can use that option as well.

```
     # Get scroll height
      last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
      limit=500
      while True:
         # Scroll down to to a limit
         driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0," + limit + ");")

         # Wait to load page
         time.sleep(1)
         # increase the scroll height
         limit=limit+500
         # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
         new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
         if new_height == last_height:
             break
         last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not that useful. Spend a minute to add some explanation of what the code does and why it would answer the question/be helpful to solve the problem.